# Не применяется условие к алиасу колонки mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

При выполнении запроса

```
SELECT
  `people`.`id`,
  CONCAT_WS(' ', `people`.`lastname`, `people`.`firstname`, `people`.`fathersname`) as `fio`,
  `positions`.`name` as `position`
FROM `people`    
INNER JOIN `staff` ON `staff`.`id` = `people`.`staff_id`
INNER JOIN `departments` ON `departments`.`id` = `staff`.`department_id`
INNER JOIN `positions` ON `positions`.`id` = `staff`.`position_id`
WHERE `fio` = 'Суровый Эдуард Петрович'
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Unknown column 'fio' in 'where clause'

При отсечении условия WHERE запрос успешно отрабатывает и возвращает указанные в  SELECT поля.

Comment: Подсократил блок кода, чтобы он влезал по ширине (видно поле `fio`) и в высоту, для компактности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алиас поля выходного набора не существует на момент выполнения секции WHERE.

Возможные решения:

1. Копирование выражения в секцию WHERE вместо алиаса
2. Перенос условия в секцию HAVING

Comment: В точку! Спасибо, использовал HAVING т.к. условие поиска составляется динамически.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте, какая очередность выполнения операторов во время запроса. Например, [тут](http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/7848)

Ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT people.id, CONCAT_WS(' ', people.lastname, people.firstname, people.fathersname) as fio, positions.name as position
FROM people
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.id = people.staff_id
INNER JOIN departments ON departments.id = staff.department_id
INNER JOIN positions ON positions.id = staff.position_id
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', people.lastname, people.firstname, people.fathersname) = 'Суровый Эдуард Петрович'
```